# How to Refresh Django Server (Online)

Tags: django

Is possible to refresh django server online?

I want that django refesh as is in (python manage.py runserver), however
i want to make this using a django view.

How comand allow to refresh server online?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. But if you really need to, you can run unix commands from inside your python script using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess). More info and examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/1252711)

Comment: I realy need to rerun only 1 script insile a specific dir, however i 3 weeks searching about and don't get at the moiment, the only solution i found is refresh server.

Comment: "re-run only 1 script inside a specific dir" what kind of script is that? When do you need to re-run it? Why does it run when you restart your server? Why not just call that script directly when you get a request to re-run it? This sounds like you're having an XY problem (asking the wrong question for a problem you're not explaining).

Comment: its a router, its being executed only 1 time and not updating once i load a new file.

Comment: I not asking the wrong question, i need to exec a .py sile inside a django, however i cant find a way to do this.

Comment: what's a router? Is it a python script? And what do you mean "not updating once i load a new file", what new file? Please explain the details, show us the "router" and explain under which conditions it needs to run again. And yes, you are asking the wrong question, you're asking how to restart the django server whereas you should ask how do I run the script.

Comment: This is my project, look in 'app/as_dash.py", this file as_dash.py execute only one time, i want that this code identify once 'media/' files change however it dont work because it runs only one time. https://github.com/CaioEuzebio/DjangoDashboard

Comment: Why don't you wrap all that code in one or more functions that you call inside your views? for example instead of declaring `dforderbypn` globally, make a function `get_dforderbypn()` that returns it, so every time it's called, your `filename` gets recalculated (and all the data frames with it).

Comment: i tried, however i have a dispathcer and dispatcher return a error once i store all inside a function.

Comment: Then you should fix that error, there's no reason why it shouldn't work. There's no other way.

Comment: Thath, was my fear Sir. Wellm let's code, i will make some refact and return here the results.

Comment: Yes, i resolved storing all my pandas dataframes in the same router function before 'return' layout html.